# How do I link storyboard and swift in a Mac application?

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard, swiftui

I am trying to IBsegue from the story board to my subclass of NSHostingView. Is this the proper way to link storyboard and SwiftUI for a Mac application?(If not, what is the proper way?) If so, I get four errors in the subclass file:

```
import Cocoa

class hosty: NSHostingView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    @IBSegueAction func termo(_ coder: NSCoder) -> NSViewController? {
        return NSHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: ContentView())
    }
}
```

Use of undeclared type 'NSHostingView' `class hosty: NSHostingView {`
Method does not override any method from its superclass `override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {`
'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class `super.draw(dirtyRect)`
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSHostingController' `return NSHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: ContentView())`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your class name should begin with a capital, Hosty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need import `SwiftUI` and specify generics type for `NSHostingView` like below

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class hosty: NSHostingView<ContentView> {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    @IBSegueAction func termo(_ coder: NSCoder) -> NSViewController? {
        return NSHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: ContentView())
    }
}
```